# How can I deploy static content separately from my Azure solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I saw the following comment on Stack Overflow but I'm unable to find a reference to it.

```
"Yes it is. I have seen a Azure webcast from Cloud9 where the application was 
broken up. The static content like images, html, css etc were deployed separately 
than the Azure solution. The azure web app just linked to these resources"
```

Has anyone done this and have any information on how to do it?

Comment: What specifically do you need help doing? You can place the static content in a bucket somewhere (like S3) and change the reference in your MVC application. That's pretty easy.

Comment: Actually, it wouldn't be practical to place static content in S3, as you'd now incur latency + bandwidth charges between Amazon and Windows Azure clouds. Static content, for a Windows Azure site, would be most effective if stored in Windows Azure blob storage, colocated in the same data center. Concur on changing link references though.

Comment: @David, If these are just things like CSS and JavaScript, they're being accessed by the client (browser), so colocation makes no difference.

Comment: @smarx - true. I was thinking about additional access of said content within Azure roles. Ok, maybe "over" thinking... :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Joe gennari mentioned: image links, css links, etc. just need to be changed, to reference objects in blob storage. For instance: `<img src="http://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/logo.jpg" />`.

To actually get content into blob storage, you can:

- Create a little uploader app, making very simple calls to via one of the language SDKs (Java, php, .net, python, etc.).
- Upload blobs using [PowerShell cmdlets](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/downloads/) - see command documentation [here](http://wappowershell.codeplex.com/documentation).
- Use a tool such as Cerebrata's [Cloud Storage Studio](http://cerebrata.com/Products/CloudStorageStudio/) or Clumsy Leaf [CloudXplorer](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer), which lets you work with blobs in a similar way you'd work with your local file system.

You would no longer be bundling static content with your Windows Azure project. You'd upload blob updates separately (and without need for re-uploading an Azure project). This has the benefit of reducing deployment package size.

Comment: Just a note: when you upload your content, remember to mark the blob container as public.